# TypeScript handleChange for textfield and select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am building out a form using TypeScript and Material-UI components.

I want to use a change handler function that can be reused on my select change and my textfield changes.

My state and functions are as follows:

```
  const [referralData, setReferralData] = useReducer(referralReducer, {
    applicationID: applicationID || '',
    submissionId: '1',
  })

  function referralReducer(state, event) {
    return {...state, [event.name]: event.value}
  }

  function handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<{name: string; value: unknown}>) {
    const {name, value} = e.target
    setReferralData({name: name, value: value})
  }
```

I am using the material UI select and textfield components as follows:

```
            <MuiSelect
              disabled={!!applicationID}
              fullWidth={true}
              id="applicationID"
              itemList={['G2 Property']}
              label="Application"
              name={'applicationID'}
              onChange={handleChange}
              size="small"
              value={referralData.applicationID}
            />
```

and

```
            <MuiTextInput
              disabled={!referralData.applicationID}
              fullWidth={true}
              id="Submission-ID"
              label="Submission ID"
              name="Submission-ID"
              onChange={handleChange}
              size="small"
              value="30092"
            />
```

Everything seems to work fine, however I get the following error on the `onChange` of my select component.

```
Type '(e: ChangeEvent<{ name: string; value: unknown; }>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: SelectChangeEvent<unknown>, child: ReactNode) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'SelectChangeEvent<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<{ name: string; value: unknown; }>'.
      Type 'Event & { target: { value: unknown; name: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ChangeEvent<{ name: string; value: unknown; }>': nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persistts(2322)
Select.d.ts(103, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & otherProps & SelectProps<unknown>'
```

I am trying to understand why I only get the error on the Select component and not the Textfield.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the methods have different declarations for both Input and Select components. Even the type of `event` is different.

Select component: `function(event: SelectChangeEvent, child?: object) => void`

Input component: `function(event: React.ChangeEvent) => void`

Select `onChange` method: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/#select-prop-onChange

Input `onChange` method: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input/#input-prop-onChange